# Two-Way-Binding Possible In ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

Let's say I have a product object (pretty much empty) and I bind it to a Product view.  Then I click update in the view.  In my CustomModelBinder my bindingContext.Model is always null on the update request.  Is there a recommended way of me retrieving the prior model at this point or do I always have to recreate it?

Comment: I think you'll hit a lot of issues where you believe the model sent to the view can be bound to the postback form view.. the reality is considerably different, for example.. you bind a collection a products for a 'products selection', but instead get back a collection of ints that represent the product ids.. in order for the postback to make this appear as products would mean it would need to do dataaccess and pull the products automatically regardless of their need.. I think you would begin to see perf issues with pulling considerable amounts of data just to suit a paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate it from the form fields. The values you bound to the model for the GET are long gone.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps im not understanding your needs to use a CustomModelBinder, but did u concider [Data Annotations Model Binder](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471) yet?

it even comes with (serverside) validation based on simple statements like [Required] which u can put right inside your model, see [this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html)